# Voltage reference required for DAC81404

Tags: dac, voltage-reference

I want to create a driver board to control a piezo actuator. I have a [DAC81404](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/dac81404) DAC laying around, but I am confused as to how the voltage reference works.

I want to drive the piezo from -15 V to +15 V, so my full-scale voltage will be 30 V for the DAC. Do I need a 30 V voltage reference or can I use a smaller voltage reference such as the internal 2.5 V reference as an example?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the Electrical Characteristics table, an external reference also must be 2.5 V.

To get a voltage larger than 2.5 V, you need a buffer with a gain larger than one.

As it happens, this chip contains such a buffer; see section 8.3.2 "Programmable-Gain Output Buffer".

Comment: Thanks for your input. So I take it the output voltage noise then gets multiplied by the gain as well? Making it not such an attractive DAC? Would it help if I get a really precision 2.5v external reference?

Comment: The performance specifications already include the effects of the output buffer. (It is not possible to bypass the buffer, so it wouldn't be possible to measure it in any other way.)